why quojections are prequojections
While reading about quojections and prequojections in the book "Advances in the Theory of Fréchet Spaces," I'm having trouble understanding why every quojection is necessarily a prequojection. Could someone  clarify the reasoning behind this?
by the way A quojection is a Fréchet space that can be represented as a projective limit of Banach spaces connected by surjective maps. A prequojection is a Fréchet space whose bidual (the dual of its dual space) is a quojection.

It would be very useful, to make this post more helpful to general readers and easier for others to answer, if you would define "quojection" and "prequojection"

A quojection is a Frechet space that can be represented as a projective limit of Banach spaces connected by surjective maps. A prequojection is a Frechet space whose bidual (the dual of its dual space) is a quojection.

Right. Well then the reasonable guess is that application of the bidual functor to the limit describing a given quojection $V$ would yield a limit diagram for $V^{\ast\ast}$. I'm not sure of the details though, we would need to assume $(-)^{\ast\ast}$ is a continuous functor on the category of Banach spaces

I would appreciate more details if you could

I’m not sure of them! I’ll wait for someone with more confidence in this kind of functional analysis to answer

I appreciate your help anyway
